# I want to make a script that log missing images

Tags: javascript, python

**1.**I have a folder contains lots of images, rename by rules :
imagename--angle
for example :

> TE100--front
> TE200--back

each imagename will have a fix set of angle . for example image name TE100 will have 4 angle :

> TE100--front
> TE100--back
> TE100--left
> TE100--right

if it have enough 4 angle - i will note that imagename is done (no need to update more angle)

**2.**I will update these images everyday
forexample : day 1, i update an image to the folder, named TE100--front
next day, i update one more image , named TE100--back

=> I want to write a script that will :

1. Show all image name in folder and it's status : DONE if it has enough 4 angle, NOT DONE if any angle is missing.For example :

> TE100 - DONE

> TE200 - NOT DONE (missing 2 angle)

2.Allow to search by image name and check if any angle need to be add
For example :

> TE200 - NOT DONE, missing 2 angle :
>
> -TE200--front
>
> -TE200--left

**3.**Next to every row of missing image, have a button, if clicked, it will open photoshop.

Im a newbie, i have an idea but i dont know where to start , can someone help me with somekind of roadmap like this- so i can research and learn how to make the script step by step :

- what should i use to make the script (python, electron, c++....)
- should i store image path in database or just access it directly (without index the entire folder everytime because it's 200gb of images, it took a lot of times to index)
- how to monitor change when i upload new image to the folder
- simple UI

Comment: you could write a python script that prints to a .txt file with your desired output and run it whenever you want to update. This would work for #1 and #2... #3 seems like a lot more work just for a UI.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution Python + HTML report could be like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

# folder with images
folder = Path(r"d:\scripts\so\py\images_base\images")

# get files
files = list(folder.glob("*.jpg"));

# get a dict of images
images = {}
for f in files:
    img = {"back": "none", "front": "none", "left": "none", "right": "none"}
    name, side = f.stem.split("--")
    link = "<a href = '" + f.as_uri() + "'>" + f.name + "</a>"
    if name not in images:
        img[side] = link
        images[name] = img
    else:
        images[name][side]= link

# save the dict to HTML
with open(folder.parent / "report.html", "w") as f:
    f.write("<html>\n")
    f.write("<style>")
    f.write("td {text-align: center; padding: .5em; border-bottom: 1px gray solid}")
    f.write("</style>")
    f.write("<body><table>\n")
    f.write("<tr><td>IMAGE</td><td>BACK</td><td>FRONT</td><td>LEFT</td><td>RIGHT</td></tr>\n")

    for k, v in images.items():
        f.write(f"<tr><td>{k}</td><td>{v['back']}</td><td>{v['front']}</td><td>{v['left']}</td><td>{v['right']}</td></tr>\n")

    f.write("</table></body></html>")
```

If you have the folder with files:

```
TE100--back.jpg
TE100--front.jpg
TE100--left.jpg
TE100--right.jpg
TE200--back.jpg
TE200--front.jpg
TE200--left.jpg
TE300--front.jpg
```

The script will get you the file `report.html` which will look in a browser like this:

[image]

To get incompleted images you can built another report:

```
# get missing images
with open(folder.parent / "report_missing.html", "w") as f:
    f.write("<html>\n")
    f.write("<style>")
    f.write("td {text-align: center; padding: .5em; border-bottom: 1px gray solid}")
    f.write("</style>")
    f.write("<body><table>\n")
    f.write("<tr><td>IMAGE</td><td>BACK</td><td>FRONT</td><td>LEFT</td><td>RIGHT</td></tr>\n")

    for k, v in images.items():
        if "none" in [v[x] for x in v]:
            f.write(f"<tr><td>{k}</td><td>{v['back']}</td><td>{v['front']}</td><td>{v['left']}</td><td>{v['right']}</td></tr>\n")

    f.write("</table></body></html>")
```

[image]

You can copy the table in the browser and paste it into Excel. Etc.

Of course it's just a sketch.